# Link aparece fora da imagem, na página html

Tags: html, html5

```
        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/" target="_blank"><img src="img/win.png" alt="" width="150px"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://www.xbox.com/pt-BR" target="_blank"><img src="img/xbox.jpg" alt="" width="150px"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://www.office.com/?auth=2"  target="_blank"><img src="img/office.png" alt="" width="150px"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/" target="blank"><img src="img/azure.png" alt="" width="150px"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/microsoft-365/onedrive/online-cloud-storage" target="_blank"><img src="img/onedrive.jpg" alt="" width="150px"></a>
        </div>

        <style>
        div.box {
            width: 200px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        </style>

    </section>
</body>
```

O link para as páginas aparecem, porém, aparecem a esquerda da imagem, e não em cima dela.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara vc tem que por `display: inline-block;` no link, na tag `<a>`

Comment: Continuou a mesma coisa :/

Answer (score 0):

Isso não faz sentido, provavelmente você manipulou a imagem com css para alinhá-la, isso deve ter criado um quadrado ou retângulo em volta dela, faça assim:

```
    <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/" target="_blank" rel=”noopener”>
        <div class="box">
             <img src="img/win.png" alt="" width="150px">
        </div>
    </a>
```

Uma div pode ser filha de um elemento A, não existe problema nisso! É interessante você dá uma pesquisada no bootstrap, assim você pode trabalhar com o grid, ficaria mais fácil.

Sugiro que você de uma pesquisada também, sobre o target="_blank", alguém pode acabar sequestrando a conexão nesse loop para mostrar uma pagina falsa.